# Google Apps Script HTML Service Key Events

Tags: javascript, html, validation, google-apps-script

I am using Google Apps Script to create a textbox and validate that the input is numbers only.

```
$('.numbersOnly').keyup(function () {
    if (!this.value.match(/^([0-9]{0,2})$/)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').substring(0,2);
    }
});
```

and

```
<input type="text" name="height" class="numbersOnly" />
```

But it doesn't work in my web app.  The code works in JSFiddle though.work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include Jquery in your project.
Create a pag.html file like these:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div>
<input type="text" name="height" class="numbersOnly" />
<script>
$('.numbersOnly').keyup(function () {
    if (!this.value.match(/^([0-9]{0,2})$/)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').substring(0,2);
    }
});
</script>
</div>
```

And create your apps script like this:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("pag.html").evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}
```